# jose4j, decrypt JWE with symmetric key

Tags: jwt, jose4j

I'm trying to reproduce a decoding of a JWE starting from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) as an example and translating into code by using library [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home)

From site jwt.io I have the following:

HEADER:

```
{
   "alg": "HS256"
}
```

PAYLOAD:

```
{
    "sub": "1234567890",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "iat": 1516239022
}
```

VERIFY SIGNATURE:

```
HMACSHA256(
    base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
    base64UrlEncode(payload),
    Fdh9u8rINxfivbrianbbVT1u232VQBZYKx1HGAGPt2I
)
```

the secret base64 is not encoded.

Now I try to reproduce the situation with jose4j and then having as a result the same value on the encoded field, which is:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.jOJ7G4oijaDk9Tr4ntAXczd6PlI4oVvBU0_5cf7oaz4
```

Then:

```
    Key key = new HmacKey("Fdh9u8rINxfivbrianbbVT1u232VQBZYKx1HGAGPt2I".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  
    JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();
    String payload = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("sub", "1234567890")
            .add("name", "John Doe")
            .add("iat", "1516239022")
            .build()
            .toString();
    jwe.setPayload(payload);
    jwe.setHeader("alg", "HS256");
    jwe.setKey(key);
    String serializedJwe = jwe.getCompactSerialization();
    System.out.println("Serialized Encrypted JWE: " + serializedJwe);
```

However I get this error:

> org.jose4j.lang.InvalidAlgorithmException: HS256 is an unknown, unsupported or unavailable alg algorithm (not one of [RSA1_5, RSA-OAEP, RSA-OAEP-256, dir, A128KW, A192KW, A256KW, ECDH-ES, ECDH-ES+A128KW, ECDH-ES+A192KW, ECDH-ES+A256KW, PBES2-HS256+A128KW, PBES2-HS384+A192KW, PBES2-HS512+A256KW, A128GCMKW, A192GCMKW, A256GCMKW]).

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you want to do but I also think you're mixing up things here. JWTs come basically in two variants, the more common signed JWT (JWS) and the encrypted variant (JWE). JWT.io can only deal with signed tokens (header and payload are only base64url encoded). So with your JWE code you can't replicate what you see on jwt.io. JWEs have really encrypted payload. HS256 is a signature algotrithm that can be used for signed tokens but not in JWE. Read a short introduction on https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3

Answer (score 1):

HS256 is a JWS algorithm so you'd need to use `JsonWebSignature` rather than `JsonWebEncryption` to accomplish what it looks like you're trying to do.